# non-Custom UITableViewCells disappear on click or Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that I'm populating from an NSArray and whenever I click on or scroll the table *all* the TableCells go away. AFAICT there's no problem with the cell reuse identifiers and the rowList NSArray isn't doing anything funny either. Here's the relevant code. "click" never shows up in the log.

```
@interface TheTableViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * rowList;
@end

@implementation TheTableViewController
@synthesize rowList;

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rowList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    NSString *cid = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"CellReuseIdentifier_%i",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cid];
    cell = cell ? cell : [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cid];
    cell.textLabel.text = [rowList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - table view delegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"click");
}
@end
```

Comment: You've implemented the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (not didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) method. Make sure that when you are selecting a cell, the selection style does not cover your content.

Comment: @MihaiAndreiRustiuc Good eye! unfortunately correcting that doesn't seem to change anything: the "click" still isn't logged. It's not just one cell that goes, it's all the cells in the table.

Comment: it may be some XCode bug I also experienced lately. If you are using XCode 6 try also implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Nope, no change. Why would using Xcode 6 make a difference?

Comment: It's still in beta, and there are some bugs in it. Anyway, try using as cell identifier a single string. Moreover, put some breakpoints and see what happens in cellForRowAtIndexPath: when scrolling.

Comment: Nothing happens in cellForRowAtIndexPath - it's called once per cell when the table loads and that's it. Nothing happens when scrolling because all the cells disappear before you can start. The dynamic reuse identifier is actually from a previous attempt to fix this. Taking it out didn't help either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58318/discussion-between-mihai-andrei-rustiuc-and-user1958756).

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the problem was nowhere near where I thought it was. A co-worker pointed out that the tableview's delegate and datasource was getting released. I'm including the answer here in case anyone ever has/hears of a similar problem or is curious.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UITableViewController * t = [UITableViewController new];
    [self.view addSubview:t.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{t.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,640,480}]
};
```

The fix was to make "t" a property so it sticks around until we get rid of it.

```
@interface MainViewController: <
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITableViewController * t;
@end

@implementation MainViewController ()
@synthesize t;

-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UITableViewController * t = [UITableViewController new];
    [self.view addSubview:t.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{t.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,640,480}]
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This saved me from a lot of trouble.